# sed - how to exclude multiple patterns in the match

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have currently a set of seds that's working well except for one thing.

The particular expression I'm having an issue with is:

```
sed -i '/[^}.to]\.to[[:space:]]/ s/\(\S\)/expect(\1/' ../_spec_seded/"$file"
```

Right now this works fine.
Basically it looks for `.to` and insert `expect` at the start of the expression.
In particular, it excludes `}.to` when looking to match on `.to` which works.

Now I want to also exclude 'this' or 'that' from the search match.  In my case `}.to` **or** `end.to`

i.e. instead of

```
/[^}.to]\.to[[:space]]/
```

should I have:

```
/[^}.to|^end\.to]\.to[[:space]]/
/[^}.to][^end\.to]\.to[[:space]]/
/[(^}.to|end\.to)]\.to[[:space]]/
/[^(}.to|end\.to)]\.to[[:space]]/
```

would I even need to escape parens if using them like

```
/[^\(}.to|end\.to\)]\.to[[:space]]/
```

or even the `|` as well?

```
/[^\(}.to\|end\.to\)]\.to[[:space]]/
```

I'm trying to make the match work on:

```
stuff.to do thing
stuff).to do thing
this.to that
all.all.all.to do
pretend.do  # Note this edge case! (pretend contains "end"!)
```

but not on

```
this will be here }.to do
last.end}.to do
all.this at the end.to
none at allend.to
```

and

```
all.this at the 
end.to # i.e. no spaces before as it is the start of the line.
```

Negating with OR's generally (all languages) seems tricky (due to false positives).

Comment: What's the difference between the `pretend.do` and `none at allend.to` cases that one should match and the other shouldn't? And how come `pretend.do` matches when it doesn't have a `\.to[[:space:]]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pending your response to my comment on the question, here's my answer:

- First of all, `[^}.to]` doesn't do what you seem to think. It will *not* match lines that don't have the pattern `}.to`. It matches lines that have any *character* other than `.`, `}`, `t` or `o`. In other words, *many* lines.
- To make things easier, let's have `sed` print nothing by default then tell it to print everything *except* those lines matching the patterns you want to exclude:

  ```
  sed -n '/\(\bend\|}\.to\)/!p' your_file
  ```

This will print all lines not containing `end.to` at a word boundary (i.e. `allend.to` doesn't count) or `}.to`.

If, in addition you want to print only those lines that match `\.foo[[:space:]]`, simply delete lines matching unwanted patterns and add a conditional print:

```
sed -n '/\(\bend\|}\.to\)/d;/\.to[[:space:]]/p' your_file
```

Of course, between the match and the print, you can apply whatever substitution you feel like:

```
sed -n '/\(\bend\|}\.to\)/d;/\.to[[:space:]]/s/foo/bar/g;p' your_file
```

Answer (score -1):

For most cases this seems to work:

before:

```
sed -i 's/[^}.to].to[[:space:]]/).to /' ../_spec_seded/"$file"
```

after:

```
sed -i 's/[^}.to|end.to].to[[:space:]]/).to /' ../_spec_seded/"$file"
```